# Another Strange Crossword

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords, humor

Solve the strangely-shaped crossword.

Then find the answer word describing how PSE treats new users.

[image]

<sub>Sorry- no text version of the crossword image. It is difficult for me to fit all that info into text. Maybe someone else better than me can work some magic.</sub>

**Across**
1   R. Kelly believes he can.
2   Beware of taking this from mainstream media; advice
3   Thankfully, "soothing syrup" use hit this over 100 years ago.
6   When sharing, a single is OK, but a double is bad.
9   Used to drown out wife's "fix-it" requests
10  All things do this. Only kids love it. (British)
11  Would be strange if things fell this way
12  Cats carry kittens by this. Ouch!
14  Who said "Do these genes make me look fat?"
15  Bill Clinton can articulate this definition.
16  Pickles are ____icious.
17  Time required for wife to get ready
19  A few glasses of this gives you more important things to say.
20  P. Diddy's reaction to clowns
22  Evel Knievel was a regular here.
24  How I sleep when losing my religion
25  Necessary to "make it rain"
27  Possible consideration when on a cruise with mother-in-law
29  Used before an author's name
30  Well, it never bothered Elsa.
33  Let's hope their strange magic won't bring me down.
34  The first part of every ah-ha moment
36  Measure for ice cream when sad or depressed
37  Popular highball for a jolt and a buzz (abbrev.)
38  Enforces laws; often ignorant of his authority's limits. (abbrev)
39  It was water before it was cool.
40  When lost, many men resist this solution.

**Down**
3   Refuses to mate, even to avoid extinction
4   Lightning-fast version of snail mail
5   Top tech brand for high quality and ridiculous prices
6   Chronic teller of corny jokes
7   Strategy for conquering trolls
8   Princess's sensitivity-testing legume
11  Genus of a lichen likened to an old man's beard
13  Spanish masc. definite article
15  Peak: "King of Gods" lover; Low Point: Became a tormented heifer
17  Duration of humanity's love for pizza
18  These citizens get the best discounts.
20  Judge Doom to Roger
21  Skill type tested when wife finds unknown lipstick in your car
23  The face your co-worker hopes to show "that new chick from logistics"
25  In China, between a monkey and a dog
26  You can lean on me when looking out your window.
28  Wear me, or add "um" and listen to me.
31  Jed called it Texas Tea.
32  Tough word for some fiancés to say
35  My reply when strangers say of my toddler son: "She's precious!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To new users, PSE is:

> **WELCOMING**.

The solutions:

> **Across: 1** fly **2** tip **3** peak **6** dip **9** amp **10** ageing **11** up **12** nape **14** dna **15** is **16** dill **17** eons **19** ale **20** fright **22** er **24** rem **25** cash **27** maroon **29** by **30** cold **33** elo **34** ah **36** kilo **37** rbv **38** leo **39** ice **40** ask
>
>  **Down: 3** panda **4** e-mail **5** apple **6** dad **7** ignore **8** pea **11** usnea **13** el **15** io **17** eternal **18** sr **20** framer **21** improv **23** oh **25** cock **26** sill **28** alb **31** oil **32** do **35** he
>
>  (Sorry for the rather plain presentation.)

The highlighted cells:

> They grey cells spell **FLIP DIMENSIONS FOR EACH PRIMARY COLOR BLOCK**.
>
>  The crossword puzzle is a 15×15 grid, subdivided into three 5×15 columns, each marked with one of the primary colours. To "flip dimensions" means to re-arrange each 5×15 block into a 15×5 block so that the black and white cells are the same when "read" row-wise. (You can imagine this as word-wrapping a text to three times its width, if you like.)
>
>  If we do that and space out each 5×5 sub-block, we get:
>
> ```
>    red                 yellow              blue
>
>    #...# ##### #....   ##### ##### #...#   ##### #...# #####
>    #...# #.... #....   #.... #...# ##.##   ..#.. ##..# #....
>    #...# ####. #....   #.... #...# #.#.#   ..#.. #.#.# #.###
>    #.#.# #.... #....   #.... #...# #...#   ..#.. #..## #...#
>    ##.## ##### #####   ##### ##### #...#   ##### #...# #####
> ```

Comment: The question mark common to 22A and 18D is 'R' (E.R. and 'S(enio)r' citizens). The one for 15A/D is 'I' because of Io from Greek myth and [this](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/1998/09/bill-clinton-and-the-meaning-of-is.html).

Comment: Ah, thanks, @Stiv. Added it in.

Comment: Aha. And there I was wondering what a coln was.

Comment: I wasnt sure if the "flip dim" thing would be tough, but you got it quickly, so i guess not.

Comment: Well, I tried other things first, but I thought it was fair. (But I misread "color blocks" as "col(umns) or blocks" at first, which had me stumped.)